# Reverse a linked list in perl

Tags: perl, linked-list

So I know that there are hundred examples on Stack overflow, and in fact i have used all the information from there - so this is what i have

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $head= undef;
my $tail=\$head;

open FILE, "<datastored.txt" or die $!;

while (<FILE>){
    my $node = {
                "data" => $_ , 
                "next" => undef
            };
    $$tail=$node; 
    $tail = \$node->{"next"}; 
};
print Dumper $head; #before reversing
$head = reverse_list($head);
print Dumper $head; #after reversing
sub reverse_list{
    my ($list) =@_[0];
    my $previous = undef;
    while ($list->{next}){
        $forward = $list->{next}; 
        $list->{next}= $previous; 
        $previous = $list; 
        $list=$forward; 
    };
    return $previous;   
};
```

and this is the output I get

```
#this is the output before reversing (normal linked list)
$VAR1 = {
          'next' => {
                      'next' => {
                                  'next' => {
                                              'next' => undef,
                                              'data' => 'line 4
'
                                            },
                                  'data' => 'line 3
'
                                },
                      'data' => 'line 2
'
                    },
          'data' => 'line 1
'
        };
#this is the linked list after reversing (WITHOUT THE LAST DATA VARIABLE - "line 4")
$VAR1 = {
          'next' => {
                      'next' => {
                                  'next' => undef,
                                  'data' => 'line 1
'
                                },
                      'data' => 'line 2
'
                    },
          'data' => 'line 3
'
        };
```

Note - the content of the file `datastored.txt` is simply

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

So my question is where is the data "line 4" gone and what should i change to  ACTUALLY reverse the linked list without losing any value.

Comment: You code doesn’t compile, because you forgot a `my` in front of your assignment to `$forward`.  However, I have an additional suggestion for you, beyond @dirkgently’s answer. You should install the CPAN `Data::Dump` module and change your two instances of `print Dumper` to `dd` (after change your `use Data::Dump`). The output is much much easier to read than `Data::Dumper`’s is.

Comment: Well you could remove `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of the file. Also thanks for the suggestion - Data::Dump, I'll definitely try that out

Comment: I see you still have teh `my $tail=\$head;` bug?

Comment: @ikegami, well I am still waiting for you to explain it to me in further detail, as to why it is wrong? Because it seems to be working for me (also that is how its done in the book). Though I would love to be proved wrong. So could you please explain it to me?

Comment: If every time you did an addition, you added `+0`, would you consider that wrong? It would be useless code whose only purpose is to confuse. That's what you have. At the very least, your variable name is wrong. It looks like $head is the head node and $tail is the tail node, but that's not the case. $head is the head node, but $tail is *a reference* to the tail node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reversal sub-routine is almost correct. However, it misses the last entry (i.e. adding it in the final reversed list) because of the condition you are using. You have two options:

1. Change the `while ($list->{next})` to `while ($list)` and make the code more idiomatic.
2. Add a `$list->{next}= $previous;` after the end of the `while` loop to add back the last remaining node to your reversed list. (Think of a list of two elements and see what your code does).

Comment: wow!!!! i preferred option number 1 and it worked fine! I had a choice to make- try to fix it myself by understand why it is failing or ask on stack overflow. I choose the former 5 hours back but thankfully i let go off my ego and asked the question. Mentally drained trying to figure out why it wasn working. THANK YOU. have a great day! :)

Comment: @seleniumnewbie: That's a good choice. Using an idiomatic approach makes maintenance easier. It's perfectly fine to ask SO as long as you've thought about it for a while and can't come up with an answer.